# Is this example correct?

Tags: calculus, limits

If I was to provide an example for a function $f$ and a function $g$ such that it meets the conditions below, will the example I have typed below be correct?

Conditions:

$\lim \limits_{x \to 1}$ $f(x) = 2$ , $\lim \limits_{u \to 2}$ $g(u) = 3$, and $\lim \limits_{x \to 1}$ $g(f(x)) = 42$

This is the example I came up with:

$$g(u) = \begin{cases}u+1 & u\neq2 \\ 42 & u = 2 \end{cases},\ \ \ f(x) = 2x .$$

Here I am assuming the limit definition for composite functions, I am not sure if that is correct

Comment: What is your $g$?

Comment: sorry made a mistake while typing

Comment: How do you know that $\lim_{x\to 1} g(f(x))=42$?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your function $f$ and $g$ definitely satisfy

$$\lim_{x\to 1} f(x) = 2,\ \ \lim_{u\to 2} g(u) = 3,$$

however, if you calculate the third limit, you get

$$\lim_{x\to 1} g(f(x)) = \lim_{x\to 1} g(2x) = \lim_{x\to 2} g(x) = 3,$$

which is not $42$. The reason is that you only define $g(2) = 42$, but $\lim_{x\to 2} g(x)$ has nothing to do with $g(2)$!

Due to the second condition, there's not much you can do for $g$. Now try to change $f$. Indeed I think you just think too hard, there's a simpler $f$ that satisfies your first and third conditions (using the same $g$).

Comment: So it is possible for me to find an f for the same g i have?

Comment: @Mat : Yes, think of a function $f$ simpler than $2x$, which still satisfy $\lim_{x\to 1} f(x)  =2$.

Comment: i am kind of stumped at the moment, and also the second part of the piecewise function is useless right? (42, u = 2). The simplest i can see it to be is x+1 but that doesn't seem to work out

Comment: There are functions that is simpler than linear functions..... And think of that $g$, if $f(x)$ moves away from $2$, then $g(f(x)) = f(x) + 1$ and that will be far from $42$. So you want that $f$ to stay at $2$ for all $x$, so.....

Comment: Yes. Then this together with $g$ would satisfy all the conditions. @Mat

Comment: How can it satisfy, lim x--> 1 g(f(x)) = 42. I am confused about that

Comment: $\lim_{x\to 1} g(f(x)) =  \lim_{x\to 1} g(2) = \lim_{x\to 1} 42$. This is limit of a constant function... @Mat